# Update Slider for audio player using vue and howler

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, howler.js

I am creating an audio player using Vue and howler js. But I am facing some issue with updating the seek bar. Functionalities like play, pause, seeking are done but I am facing issue with seek bar updation while audio is playing.
Is there any way of doing that?

Code Link - https://codesandbox.io/s/element-plus-spa-forked-78zs4?file=/src/App.vue